# AngularJS - Losing controller scope within method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

Angular noob here. I'm trying to create a form as a directive. `ng-submit` calls a controller action, but, within that method, I don't have access to the controllers scope, ie. `$scope`.

Here's the part that's really confusing me. On my laptop and my desktop, the first time I dropped into `debugger` within the `submit()`, `$scope` was still in scope. Every subsequent time, it's not.

I had a coworker test this code, and they can't reproduce it.

EDIT: If I do not drop into debugger at that point in `$scope.submit` it works fine.

#### course-material-form.js.coffee

```js
angular
  .module 'app'
  .directive 'courseMaterialForm', () ->
    restrict: 'EA'
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/coursework/course-material/templates/_form.html'
    scope:
      book: '='
      model: '='
    controller: 'CourseMaterialFormCtrl'
```

#### course-material-form-ctrl.js.coffee

```js
angular
  .module 'app'
  .controller 'CourseMaterialFormCtrl', ($scope) ->
    $scope.submit = () ->

    return
```

#### _form.html.haml

```
%form.form-compact#course-material-form{ "ng-submit" => "submit()" }
  %fieldset.row
    .form-group.col-xs-12
      %label Title
      %input{ type: 'text', "ng-model" => " book.title " }

    .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-12
      %label Author
      %input{ type: 'text', "ng-model" => " book.author " }

  %fieldset.row
    .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-12
      %label Publisher
      %input{ type: 'text', "ng-model" => " book.publisher " }

    .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-12
      %label Publication Year
      %input{ type: 'text', "ng-model" => " book.publication_date " }

    .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-12
      %label Edition
      %input{ type: 'text', "ng-model" => " book.edition " }

    .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-12
      %label ISBN
      %input{ type: 'text', "ng-model" => " book.isbn " }

  %fieldset.row
    .form-group.col-xs-12
      %label Description
      %textarea{ "ng-model" => "book.description" }

  %fieldset.row.hidden
    .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-6
      %label URL
      %input{ type: 'text' }
```

#### _modal.html.haml

```
.modal-dialog.modalbox-dialog.coursework-form-modal
  .modal-content

    %header.modal-header.modal-header-lg
      .modal-heading
        %span{ "ng-if" => "!book" } Add
        %span{ "ng-if" => "book" } Edit
        Course Material

      %button.modal-close-btn.modal-close-icon{ "ng-click" => "$dismiss()" }
        %i.fa.fa-times-circle

    .modal-body
      %course-material-form{ model: "model", book: "book" }

    .modal-footer
      %button.btn.btn-primary.modal-footer-btn{ form: "course-material-form",
                                                type: "submit" }
        %span{ "ng-if" => "!book" } Create
        %span{ "ng-if" => "book" } Save
      %button.btn.btn-outline.modal-footer-btn{ "ng-click" => "$dismiss()",
                                                type: "button" }
        Close
```

Comment: I suggest to reduce the lines of codes while you constantly check whether the error is still there. This is still quite much of code right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer. I was not actually calling `$scope` from within the controller method. If you `$scope.book` then `$scope` is available in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The `submit` function from your `controller` and from your `directive` are not the same. They belong to different `$scope`. More info about it on section "Isolating the Scope of a Directive" from the [Directive's guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Since you are isolating the scope for the directive, you should "expose" the submit function from your controller to your directive like that:

```
scope: {
    book: '=',
    model: '=',
    submit: '&' // <- that's what you need
}
```

Then on your `_modal.html`, pass the a new attribute:

```
.modal-body
    %course-material-form{ model: "model", book: "book", submit: "submit()" }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? Shouldn't the `$scope` of the controller be exposed in the associated directive?

Comment: That would limit the power of directives. You don't want always to expose the Controller $scope to a directive, in case directives are under a ngRepeat, things would get trickier. If you want to reuse the Ctrl's $scope, set scope to true instead of passing a object. However, you will get in other problems later. Read the section "Isolating the Scope of a Directive" on this page here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive